# Python - Sending an argument as a struct

Tags: python, struct

I am working with an API that requires me to give 3 arguments.

```
string sessionKey
int    serverId
struct date details
       dateTime.iso8601 startDate - Optional, unless endDate is provided.
       dateTime.iso8601 endDate - Optional.
```

I am not sure how to define a struct in this this case. I am calling the API this way.

```
>>> server.system.provisioning.snapshot.listSnapshots(sessionKey,1000078204, {datetime.now() , datetime.now()})
```

So im defining my `struct` with the syntax:

```
{datetime.now() , datetime.now()}
```

This gives me an ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/xmlrpc/client.py", line 512, in __dump
f = self.dispatch[type(value)]
KeyError: <class 'set'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1098, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1431, in __request
    allow_none=self.__allow_none).encode(self.__encoding)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/xmlrpc/client.py", line 951, in dumps
    data = m.dumps(params)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/xmlrpc/client.py", line 504, in dumps
    dump(v, write)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/xmlrpc/client.py", line 516, in __dump
    raise TypeError("cannot marshal %s objects" % type(value))
TypeError: cannot marshal <class 'set'> objects
```

Am I defining the `struct` wrong ?

Comment: This question didn't have anything to do with [tag:c]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In XML-RPC (which your error traceback indicates you're using), a "struct" is what Python calls a "dict(ionary)", but you're trying to use a `set` instead.  You need to create a `dict` using the key names given in the API documentation (i.e., `startDate` and `endDate`), thus:

```
>>> server.system.provisioning.snapshot.listSnapshots(sessionKey,1000078204, {"startDate": datetime.now(), "endDate": datetime.now()})
```